# Can't get acceleration sensor mpu-92/65 to work with pi zero w

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I want to use an mpu-92/65 acceleration sensor with my raspberry pi zero w.

Therefore I...

1. ...soldered the 20-Pin-Header onto my raspi.
2. ...soldered the pin header onto the mpu-92/65
3. ...did the wiring like this:

[image: wiring]

Then did following configuration:

1. ..I installed i2c-tools via `sudo apt-get i2c-tools`
2. ..I activated the i2c interface in my raspi config

now when I do `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` the mpu 92/65 is not recognized by my raspi - I can only see an empty register.

How can I make my raspi recognize the mpu-92/65?

Comment: To rule out the obvious did you reboot?

Comment: It's also worth strapping ADO high or low to make sure a valid I2C address is set.  Who knows if the module has default pulls on ADO.